# Python + sqlite3: получить id человека и перенести его в другую таблицу

Tags: python, sqlite3

Привет всем,
У меня есть следующий код:

```
c.execute("SELECT id FROM test_table WHERE name = (?) ", (first_name,))
data_2 = c.fetchall()
c.execute("INSERT INTO wo_table(wo_name) VALUES(?)",
          (data_2,))
conn.commit()
```

Проблема что я постоянно получаю ошибку:

> Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Я хочу получить id человека под этим именем, и перенести его в другую таблицу которая ожидает этот id.

Comment: `print(type(first_name))` что выводит?

Comment: Пишет list......

Comment: В этом и дело, ему нужен простой тип: строка, число и т.п.

Comment: Я пытался сделать его в str() но в базе id выглядит вот так: [(1,)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` возвращает список кортежей. Вам нужно *одно* значение внутри кортежа внутри списка. Пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # use in-memory database for the demo

# create table & populate it
name = "Tom"
db.execute('CREATE TABLE Names (name TEXT)')
db.execute('INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?)', [name])

# get value
name = db.execute("SELECT name FROM Names LIMIT 1").fetchone()[0]

# insert it & show results
db.execute('INSERT INTO Names VALUES (?)', [name])
names = db.execute("SELECT name FROM Names").fetchall()
print(names)
```

#### Результат

```
[(u'Tom',), (u'Tom',)]
```

Comment: Спасибо работает1